# nginx with couchbase how to

Tags: caching, nginx, couchbase

I have search all of responces on google and still have a no-go.

I would like to try, to setup NGINX with Couchbase as a proxy.

I would like nginx to be the one that check Couchbase for data, and if its outdated will fetch from the orig server, save in the Couchbase  and then serve to the user.

I would like it to be Couchbase, becouse it's distribute, and not emptied on restart. 
Plus I would like to use it for there usage, and I do not want to have too many diferent database engines.

But I cannot find any example how to compile it on Ubuntu (working example I mean, there are few examples I am not able to follow)

Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: do you mean you need some module to compile into nginx and setup this logic in the config file?

Comment: Actually I have allready found that I only need to install OpenResty and use the MEMC module :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just for anybody who will search for this.

What you need to install is OpenResty

http://openresty.org/

And use the MEMC module to work with Couchbase as with Memcached.

Answer (score 0):

There is an nginx module to serve docs from couchbase now https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-nginx-module/

Comment: Yes, but it's not wasy to compile it... I have tried it, and I ahve not managed it :)